# AutoRest Code Generation with Gulp Task

Tags: c#, swagger, autorest

We use AutoRest to generate C# classes off the swagger file. At the moment we manually run command below:

> AutoRest.exe -Input  [-Namespace ] [-OutputDirectory
>   ] [-CodeGenerator ] [-Modeler ] [-ClientName
>   ]  [-OutputFileName ]

The problem with manual approach is that every developers will need to make sure that correct parameters are passed etc.

Wondering if anyone has successfully managed to create a gulp task to automate above so that task can be run from VS Task Runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the CommandTaskRunner extension:
https://github.com/madskristensen/CommandTaskRunner

Answer (score 1):

I am from the Autorest team and we use gulp to autogenerate the node sdk for azure. You can take a look at this gulpfile as an example. It works like a charm.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/gulpfile.js